# R function using pipes

Tags: r, function

I am trying to build a function that uses pipes from the `dplyr` package but it won't work.

Can someone help me understand why I am getting an error message?
Thanks

```
udf_ctable <- function(x){
  mtcars %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(n=n())
  }
udf_ctable(cyl)

 Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `x` is unknown
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the `!!` beore the `x`, and call with `"cyl"`:

```
udf_ctable <- function(x){
  mtcars %>% group_by(!!x) %>% summarize(n=n())
}
udf_ctable("cyl")
```

[Here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) to know more about non standard evaluation with `dplyr`.

or, thanks to @IceCreamToucan:

```
udf_ctable <- function(x){
  x <- enquo(x) # quosure of x inside the function
  mtcars %>% group_by(!!x) %>% summarize(n=n()) # !! lets dplyr evaluate x
}
udf_ctable(cyl)
```

Comment: The first answer did not quite solve it but the second one did.

Comment: equivalent to the first option : `mtcars %>% group_by_at(x) %>% summarize(n=n())`